# Append a list to a existing dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe as shown below:

```
df = 

                             A     B     
timestamp               
2022-04-08 10:07:00 29.504  50  0.85
2022-04-08 10:07:01 29.731  52  0.83
2022-04-08 10:07:02 29.393  53  0.84
```

I have a list as shown:

```
B = 
[[0, 5],
 [10, 1],
 [1,40]]
```

I want to append the list to the dataframe like this

```
df = 

                             A     B    0    1
timestamp               
2022-04-08 10:07:00 29.504  50  0.85    0    5
2022-04-08 10:07:01 29.731  52  0.83    10   1
2022-04-08 10:07:02 29.393  53  0.84    1    40
```

I order to do this, I converted the list to a dataframe

```
C = pd.DataFrame(B)
C =
    0   1
0   0   5
1   10  1
2   1   40
```

In order to obtain the desired result, I tried `pd.concat` and `pd.append`. Both of the techniques did not work. The dataframe `df` has a timestamp as index and the dataframe `C` does not have timestamp index. Therefore I am finding it difficult to concatenate or append these two dataframe. Can somebody help me with a solution?

Comment: Your lead with the index is interesting, a possibility is to reset the index of your first dataframe without droping the timestamp, then concatenate the DataFrame and set the timestamp back as the index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reset_index the first df and then do pd.concat like this,

```
pd.concat([df.reset_index(), pd.DataFrame(B)], axis=1).set_index("timestamp")
```

You can later set the index for the resulting dataframe as timestamp

Answer (score 5):

You could assign `B` to two columns:

```
df[[0,1]] = B
```

Output:

```
                             A     B   0   1
timestamp                                   
2022-04-08 10:07:00 29.504  50  0.85   0   5
2022-04-08 10:07:01 29.731  52  0.83  10   1
2022-04-08 10:07:02 29.393  53  0.84   1  40
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(B)], axis = 1)
```

Demonstration:

```
cols = ['A', 'B', 'timestamp']              
data = """2022-04-08 10:07:00 29.504  50  0.85
2022-04-08 10:07:01 29.731  52  0.83
2022-04-08 10:07:02 29.393  53  0.84"""
data = [x.split('  ') for x in data.split('\n')]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = cols)
B = [[0, 5],
 [10, 1],
 [1,40]]
pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(B)], axis = 1)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Probably need to pass `ignore_index=True`

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you need is this:

```
df_add = pd.concat(frames, axis=1)
```

where frames=[df, B]

this example should help you to do what you need:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame([(1,2),(3,4),(5,6)], columns=['a','b'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame([(100,200),(300,400),(500,600)], columns=['a','b'])

frames = [df1, df2]
df_add = pd.concat(frames, axis=1)

print(df_add)
```